# How to create a custom dashed line separator?

Tags: itext

Using DottedLineSeparator class i am able to draw dotted line separator in itext. Similarly is it possible to draw continuous hyphens like '---------------------' as separator in a PdfPCell?

I checked the example [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=242). Is any other solutions available?

Comment: I'm about to answer your question, but I'm in doubt. Do you want to draw a dashed line similar to what you'd do with the `DottedLineSeparator`, or do you want to create a `PdfPCell` with a dashed line border. The former requires me to write an example, the latter is already explained here: [Dotted Line for cell border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117321/dotted-line-for-cell-border). If you study the example, you'll see that I created a border that consists of hyphens.

Comment: Intention was to draw dashed line. Similar to DottedLineSeparator and i could see your implementation below. Based on your comment on considering PdfPCell border to draw dashed line, i would like to try it following the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117321/dotted-line-for-cell-border) shared. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LineSeparator` class can be used to draw a solid horizontal line. Either as the equivalent of the `<hr>` tag in HTML, or as a separator between two parts of text on the same line. The `DottedLineSeparator` extends the `LineSeparator` class and draws a dotted line instead of a solid line. You can define the size of the dots by changing the line width and you get a method to define the gap between the dots.

You require a dashed line and it's very easy to create your own `LineSeparator` implementation. The easiest way to do this, is by extending the `DottedLineSeparator` class like this:

```
class CustomDashedLineSeparator extends DottedLineSeparator {
    protected float dash = 5;
    protected float phase = 2.5f;

    public float getDash() {
        return dash;
    }

    public float getPhase() {
        return phase;
    }

    public void setDash(float dash) {
        this.dash = dash;
    }

    public void setPhase(float phase) {
        this.phase = phase;
    }

    public void draw(PdfContentByte canvas, float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury, float y) {
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.setLineWidth(lineWidth);
        canvas.setLineDash(dash, gap, phase);
        drawLine(canvas, llx, urx, y);
        canvas.restoreState();
    }
}
```

As you can see, we introduce two extra parameters, a `dash` value and a `phase` value. The `dash` value defines the length of the `hyphen`. The `phase` value tells iText where to start (e.g. start with half a hyphen).

Please take a look at the [CustomDashedLine](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/CustomDashedLine) example. In this example, I use this custom implementation of the `LineSeparator` like this:

```
CustomDashedLineSeparator separator = new CustomDashedLineSeparator();
separator.setDash(10);
separator.setGap(7);
separator.setLineWidth(3);
Chunk linebreak = new Chunk(separator);
document.add(linebreak);
```

The result is a dashed line with hyphens of 10pt long and 3pt thick, with gaps of 7pt. The first dash is only 7.5pt long because we didn't change the `phase` value. In our custom implementation, we defined a phase of 2.5pt, which means that we start the hyphen of 10pt at 2.5pt, resulting in a hyphen with length 7.5pt.

[image]

You can use this custom `LineSeparator` in the same way you use the `DottedLineSeparator`, e.g. as a `Chunk` in a `PdfPCell`.

Answer (score 0):

```
double wPage = doc.PageSize.Width;
double hPage = doc.PageSize.Height;

cb.MoveTo(0,hPage/2);
for (int i = 0; i < wPage; i+=5)
{
    cb.LineTo(i, hPage / 2);
    i += 5;
    cb.MoveTo(i, hPage / 2);
}
```

this is a solution too :))

Comment: How exactly does this easily be used *as separator in a PdfPCell*? Drawing a line is not the real problem here. Automatically drawing one in content itext is asked to layout automatically, that's what this question is about at its core. And by the way, drawing dotted lines like you do puts a larger burden on pdf viewers than doing it like bruno using `canvas.setLineDash`.